# How to add new Action buttons to related list?

Tags: related-list, custom-console-components, subtab-apps

We are using the Service Console app to log incoming calls as cases. Our current process is to use Global Search to find the Account, find the contact and create a new case on from the contact. I am trying to save some clicks by adding a Left Sidebar Component to the Account view that brings in the Contacts related list: 
[image: Subtab Components]

This works great, actually. I can see the related list of contacts in the account view. But I was to add a button next to each contact in the list for "New Case". Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, at this time the native Related List components do not support custom buttons. In fact, they do not support certain standard buttons either:

- Add to Campaign
- Send an Email

One alternative for you might be to tweak your process:

- User opens account
- User opens contact from your sidebar
- You add a New Case quick-action to your contacts page layout
- User clicks your New Case action to create the case